# VBA, unable to use a dynamic lastrow reference in a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following code and am getting an object error on my formula.  Having googled and looked into a few different links, I am not finding an appropriate way to use 'last row' in a formula.

```
Sub Auto_populate()

Dim LastRow1 As Integer

LastRow1 = Sheets("Line A").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Sheets("Overview").Range("D2").Formula = "='Line A'! C & LastRow1"

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "Auto_Populate"

End Sub
```

I am unsure how to get my formula to allow my use of a reference cell from another sheet.  Any help getting this to function as intended would be appreciated!

Background: I am creating an overview sheet (a dashboard) for another person.  They have several people do weekly audits and wants to track more easily what's happening.  Each item audited has its own sheet (a single person is responsible for each sheet).  I will be adding other code to this later, but my first hurdle is making sure i can reference the last row in a specific column.  This is my first pass at this, so there may be better options on how to complete the task at hand.  Please let me know if you can think of another.  I was directed to look into an error handler, though I have not read enough on that to assess if that would fit my needs.

Other info:

26 sheets (using "Line" in the code, e.g. Line A) with 1 overview.

I will have this autopopulate (using application.ontime and also workbook_open).  I will also add in a script for color formatting the font on the overview to indicate if an audit has not been performed for the current week.

Comment: Is this the exact code you're using?  I see a major typo.

Comment: yes, this is the code i'm using.  the output i'm getting, when i execute, displays #NAME? in the output cell listing ='Line A'!D:D & LastRow1

Comment: You need to be careful with your quotes basically.

Comment: Corrected after jbarker2160 timed in; thanks and sorry for having to bother with my question.  I will accept his answer when the time is up (have to wait another 4 minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line `Sheets("Overview").Range("D2").Formula = "='Line A'! C & LastRow1"`

Should be: `Sheets("Overview").Range("D2").Formula = "='Line A'!C" & LastRow1`

If you look in the formula of the cell you'd see: ='Line A'! C & LastRow1 which is not a valid formula.

Also, you instantiated the variable `LastRow` but you're using `LastRow1` in your code.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I was unaware that I could leave the & LastRow1 outside of the quotations for the quote.  (Still learning this as I go).

Comment: You had a very good question.  Do not ever be embarrassed to ask.

Comment: I appreciate that.  It's hard to not be critical on oneself when the issue is much apparent to another.

Comment: I come here in the hopes that what I haven't seen in hours of beating my head on the keyboard will be blatantly obvious to someone else within 10 seconds!

Comment: @FreeMan, I agree.  I wish I had a pair programming partner for VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Dim LastRow1 As Long
LastRow1 = Sheets("Line A").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Sheets("Overview").Range("D2").Formula = "='Line A'! C" & LastRow1
```

**EDIT#1:**

[image]

Comment: The posted code will not return a valid formula.  There is an extraneous space.

Comment: @jbarker2160 ............you are correct about the extra space...........fortunately Excel automatically removes the space........see my **EDIT#1** ..........but you are correct in that the code should not include it.

Comment: That does not work for me in Excel 2010 or Excel 2013 or Excel 2003 and since this is a version agnostic question it's better to use compatible code.

Comment: @jbarker2160  You are correct, but it is strange that it works for me using Excel 2007.

Comment: Excel 2007 was the biggest thorn in my side for many years.  During the upgrade from 2003, there were many macros that worked for our users that stopped working after the upgrade.  The only solution was to use `Option Explicit` and `Dim` every variable.  I had to do this to hundreds of user-created workbooks.  If the macro was created in 2007, dynamic variables were allowed, but then the workbooks wouldn't work in 2003...

Comment: @pnuts  I believe that *jbarker2160* is facing some kind of Excel configuration issue.........this kind of thing is really tough to debug because we can not replicate what he is seeing